# I am new to react and I am just trying to run a simplest react js file in my browser. But I am unable to run

Tags: reactjs

Please note that I do not want to create-react-app, I just want to try it on my local system.

I did following

in my /Users/me/reactwork, I created 2 files clock.html and clock.js
then in Chrome browser, I enter /Users/me/reactwork/clock.html. I expect to see my clock but I dont
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run react files you need basic react packages within your files and then you can use '.jsx' extension. By that way you can make it as single file called "clock.jsx".

And then you run this command in your terminal "npm start" it launches in new browser.

https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

The above link helps to guide you step-by-step process.

Comment: wowww  ...... its works fine really thank you sooo much